# Casting PHP variables to JS in Wordpress with google maps

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I am having some trouble casting a PHP variable to JS. I need to get Lat and Long for a google map, however it will not work with the following code:

PHP (Wordpress):

```
$lat = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'lat', true );
$long = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'long', true );
```

The Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var LatVar = '<?php echo $lat; ?>';
    var LngVar = '<?php echo $long; ?>';
    var myLatLng = {lat: LatVar, lng: LngVar};
</script>
```

If i insert the Lat and Long manually the map works. I have tested that the PHP get the variables correctly, since when using `echo $lat` or `print_r($lat`)` i get the correct data e.g. 9.916599

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting();` Additionally, what do you get with `console.log(LatVar);` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the lat and long variables should be floating points.So try removing the quotes.

So your code should be :

```
<script>
var LatVar = <?php echo $lat; ?>;
var LngVar = <?php echo $long; ?>;

var myLatLng = {lat: LatVar, lng: LngVar};
</script>
```

Also, I recommend you checking the source code of the rendered page to see if the php echos the variable values there ( with or without quotes. If it is rendering with quotes removing them may fix the issue ). If this is not helping you, get us more details.

PS:- I believe you are using a *.php extension for your file ( Even big programmers make that mistake ).